# Restarting with windowsapi reloader

Tags: python, flask

I run my flask code. at first, it was ok but after sometimes it doesn't work and I got this error:

> Restarting with windowsapi reloader

My Code:

```
x = pd.read_csv('clas.csv')

app = Flask(__name__) 

@app.route('/<x>') 
class QuotesView(FlaskView):
    def index(self):  
        return "<br>".join(x)
QuotesView.register(app)
     
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

In

```
@app.route('/<x>') 
class QuotesView(FlaskView):
    def index(self):  
        return "<br>".join(x) QuotesView.register(app)
```

surely, it was not as in the question, you have changed something, I think the original code was

```
@app.route('/<x>') 
def index(self):  
   return "<br>".join(x) QuotesView.register(app)
```

then you decided to include this function in a class `class QuotesView(FlaskView)` so nothing goes as before.

is not it? :)

**Based on the comments below**

The code in the question gives the error message `NameError: name 'FlaskView' is not defined` and not the error message you mentioned, so surely something was changed.

Comment: thnx for your attention. but I didnt change anything. I want to combine class and flask and finally found this code in forums.